# Razorpay payment report integration issue

Tags: node.js, razorpay

I want to integrate **razorpay payment report** directly from `razorpay` on my dashboard of ERP.

I am using `const await instance.payments.all()` method, but getting data of all like failed created and captured. I don't want to filter it after getting data. I want data to be filtered from `razorpay` itself. How to do that?

Comment: Razorpay doesn't have specific `end-point` to fetch only the preferred `status` (say `captured`) payments.  Do check with the [Razorpay Docs](https://razorpay.com/docs/api/payments/).